# GrapEdt crash when move renderer window to computer second screen [ DirectShow]

Tags: directshow, graphedit

I have simple direct Direct Show Filter:

```
 Source ---> Decoder --->Renderer
```

I run the filter with microsoft Graph Edt Tool.Its work fine....

But when i move the renderer window to **my computer second screen it crash...**

I get the error :

```
The application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way...
```

Why it works just at first computer screen and crash when move to second? Any ideas...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely: Decoder fails to gracefully handle graph pause/stop command OR error getting buffer from downstream filter.

More details needed for more ideas. If you have crash, you got to have crash call stack then.